# How to call a child class method C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class and a child class, in the latter there is a method that is not present in the base class. Having several child classes with different methods, I need to declare an array of the type of the base class, but this way I cannot call the methods of the child classes. Here's my code:

**Base class**

```
public class Athlete{
  protected string name;

  public Athlete(string n)
  {
    this.name=n;
  }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class Swimmer:Athlete{
   string team;

  public Swimmer(string n, string t):Base(string n)
  {
    this.team=t;
  }
  public string Swim()
  {
    return "I'm swimming!!!!" ;
  }
}
```

**Program**

```
  Athete test = New Swimmer("John","Tigers");
  Console.WriteLine(test.Swim()); //Error!!
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance to anyone that will help me.

Comment: Your variable is declared as type Athlete and therefore has no method called Swim. Therefore, you wouldn't attempt to call the Swim method on it. You'd need to declare your variable as type Swimmer instead. There *are* ways around this like casting and reflection - but they generally shouldn't be used in cases like this. If your code expects to be working with someone who can Swim, then it should be working with a Swimmer variable and not an Athlete variable.

Comment: `((Swimmer)test).Swim();` might work, or `if( test is Swimmer) { ((Swimmer)test).Swim(); }` although in general I also thinks this looks like polymorphism gone astray.

Comment: @topsail Your code would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), one of the 5 tenants of SOLID. I wouldn't recommend that. As a reminder: "Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
//program
Console.WriteLine(((Swimmer)test).Swim());
```

Comment: This is a very poor solution to your problem. If you knew that `test` was a Swimmer, why didn't you just declare the variable as a Swimmer in the first place, as shown in Nick's answer? Then you'd avoid the ugly and unnecessary casting.

Comment: Because the next step is to create an array of Athete in which I have to insert object of different types, like swimmer .

Comment: So? That doesn't change anything I said. You can still add a `Swimmer` object to an `Athelete[]` since `Swimmer` inherits from `Athlete`. See [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4TD7I). Take a closer look at Nick's answer - it's simpler and cleaner than yours.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You're not setting the value of Athlete correctly.  It shouldn't pass the type, only the value to initialise the base class.  In addition, you're using Base (uppercase B), which in my experience is used to mark a constructor as the "base" constructor in the class, when you have more than on constructor in your class.  To set the values of the parent object, you should use ***base(val)*** (lowercase)

Try changing the constructor signature of Swimmer to the following:

```
public Swimmer(string n, string t) : base(n)
{
    this.team = t;
}
```

This will correctly pass the value of n to the constructor of Athlete for you.

Full Code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] arge)
    {
        Swimmer s = new Swimmer("Nick", "My Team");
        Console.WriteLine(s.Swim());
    }
}    

public class Athlete
{
    protected string name;

    public Athlete(string n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
}

public class Swimmer : Athlete
{
    string team;

    public Swimmer(string n, string t) : base(n)
    {
        this.team = t;
    }
    public string Swim()
    {
        return "I'm swimming!!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, it does not address the actual question.

Comment: @mason The constructor of Swimmer, the base expects the value of "n", where as in the original posting, a member declaration is being passed, no?  - Swimmer(string n, string t) :Base(string n)

Comment: @mason - My apologies for not explaining that well enough in my answer